# All external DNS queries fail from within docker container

Tags: docker, dns, docker-swarm

Current docker version: `1.13.1, build 092cba3`.

Contents of /etc/resolv.conf:

```
search mycompany.local
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

(real company name obfuscated).

`nslookup` on the host itself is 100% fine, but from within container any external hostname look fails (can't event run `apt-get update`).
The same symptoms persist in all my hosts in the 4-node cluster.
Note that internal service name resolution seems to be working between the containers.

Running the same application directly on my laptop (on same office network) hostnames resolve fine.

This is becoming a bit of a slow moving disaster.

The cluster involved is still a pre-1.12 build, it that might have any bearing.

Comment: Ok, I can see that the nameserver entry for 127.0.0.11 is probably(?) a problem. Duplicating tests [from here](http://www.networkcomputing.com/data-centers/docker-networking-basic-dns-configuration/2052420654) give a working container. Could it possibly be docker-compose that is causing the problem?

Comment: Oh my SOUL. After all this effort, it seems that the primary DNS server had some major headache. After our support guys restated the dns service, all of a sudden things starting working again. WHY my nslookup testing on the hosts did not fail - I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, the `lo` or localhost interface will have the address 127.0.0.1/8 (i.e. netmask 255.0.0.0). That netmask covers this entire range:

```
127.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255
```

Since 127.0.0.11 falls into this range, connections to that address will attempt to route via the `lo` interface (*inside* the container) as a connected route. Unless your container has that address configured internally *and* has a DNS resolver listening on that address, this will result in a connection timeout.

You can probably solve this by either routing 127.0.0.11 out the main interface of the container (e.g. `eth0`), or by changing the DNS resolver address so it is outside of 127.0.0.0/8.

You can also set DNS server IP(s) explicitly.

```
docker run --dns 1.2.3.4                  # set one server
docker run --dns 1.2.3.4 --dns 5.6.7.8    # set multiple servers
```

Or using docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
dns: 1.2.3.4

dns:
  - 1.2.3.4
  - 5.6.7.8
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe you are technicallly correct, but after working through [this](http://www.networkcomputing.com/data-centers/docker-networking-basic-dns-configuration/2052420654) I am struggling to see WHY I end up with 127.0.0.11 in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Starting up the same container as that link (without compose), the correct nameserver lands in resolv. Also, last week this was still all working fine.The only major change was upgrading to docker 1.13

Comment: @demaniak Is the nameserver IP on your pre-1.13 container system something other than `127.0.0.*`? Normally the nameserver IP on the Linux hosting system is simply passed in as-is to the container (at least, in my experience).

Comment: prior to this mess, I had no reason to sniffing in DNS internals, so all I can say for certain is: the hosts themselves have proper nameserver in 10.0.0.* range, and dns is working. All containers for this app, deployed with compose in this cluster has the `127.0.0.11` nameserver (external name resolution failing). hm, should perhaps edit question to clear that up: internal service name resolution actually seems fine.Just usually do not consider that "DNS" per-se.

Comment: @demaniak Have you tried setting the DNS server(s) explicitly? I updated my answer with examples.

Comment: I have been trying to avoid that for potability's sake, but I will try that just to verify that it behaves as expected. IF the containers then still only has the 12.0.0.* as namesserver in resolv, I assume that will point to some serious underlying problems?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the setup I use:

1. Install dnsmasq.
2. Run `echo interface=docker0 > /etc/dnsmasq.d/docker`
3. Restart dnsmasq.
4. Add ***--dns 172.17.0.1*** to you docker-run or to the Docker daemon (adding it to the **DOCKER_OPTS** variable in /etc/default/docker or editing the **ExecStart** directive in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service).
5. Restart Docker.

Now you have all your containers pointing to Dnsmasq as a DNS resolver. Another plus side is that in your entries in /etc/hosts are resolved as well.